# Ruby The Hard Way Ex 25

Tags: ruby

I am trying [Ruby The Hard Way Ex 25](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex25.html). I get the expected result for this command:

```
Ex25.print_first_word(words)
# => All
```

But for another command, instead of the expected result:

```
Ex25.print_last_word(words)
# => wait.
```

I get this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/Me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
```

Does anyone have any idea what this could be referring to?

EDIT:

This is what I put for Exercise 25:

```
module Ex25

    def Ex25.break_words(stuff)
        words = stuff.split(' ')
        return words
    end

        def Ex25.sort_words(words)
            return words.sort
        end

            def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
                word = words.shift
                puts word
            end

            def Ex25.print_last_word(words)
                word = word.pop
                puts word
            end

def Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    return Ex25.sort_words(words)
end


def Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
end

def Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
    words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
end

end
```

And this is what I put in terminal, with the associated errors:

```
MiniBean:ruby me$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > require "./ex25.rb"
 => true 
2.2.0 :002 > sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
 => "All good things come to those who wait." 
2.2.0 :003 > words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
 => ["All", "good", "things", "come", "to", "those", "who", "wait."] 
2.2.0 :004 > words
 => ["All", "good", "things", "come", "to", "those", "who", "wait."] 
2.2.0 :005 > sorted_words = Ex25.sort_words(words)
 => ["All", "come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"] 
2.2.0 :006 > sorted_words
 => ["All", "come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"] 
2.2.0 :007 > Ex25.print_first_word(words)
All
 => nil 
2.2.0 :008 > Ex25.print_last_word(words)
NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.0 :009 > words
 => ["good", "things", "come", "to", "those", "who", "wait."] 
2.2.0 :010 > Ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
All
 => nil 
2.2.0 :011 > Ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
    from (irb):11
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.0 :012 > sorted_words
 => ["come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"] 
2.2.0 :013 > sorted_words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
 => ["All", "come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"] 
2.2.0 :014 > sorted_words
 => ["All", "come", "good", "things", "those", "to", "wait.", "who"] 
2.2.0 :015 > Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
All
NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:31:in `print_first_and_last'
    from (irb):15
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.0 :016 > Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
All
NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
    from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:37:in `print_first_and_last_sorted'
    from (irb):16
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.0 :017 >
```

Comment: Where is the `pop` method defined?

Comment: In both methods, you are passing-in an array as an argument.  But--in the`print_last_word` method--the `words` array has a value of `nil`, so the `undefined method` error is thrown.  Beyond that, there's not enough code here to pinpoint your problem.  Your best bet (in terms of getting help on SO) is to post the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Apologies, I linked to the code I used in the question.

@RogueBaneling I don't know what it means to define a pop method.

@orde I completed the exercise in same order at the book, creating a file called Ex 25, and running the code as suggested, but instead of getting a 'nil' message, I got 'NoMethodError: undefined method `pop' for nil:NilClass
 from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:18:in `print_last_word'
 from /Users/me/Documents/RUBY/ex25.rb:37:in `print_first_and_last_sorted'
 from (irb):16'

Comment: @orde Thank you for the advise, I've now put the full code I used. This is the exercise I am trying to replicate: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: Please use proper formatting when posting code on StackOverflow. Indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces. You use *four* different indentations in your code, *none* of which is correct: 0, 4, 8, and 12 spaces, all instead of the 2 spaces which would be customary. Also, please post the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem. In your case, the error message clearly says what method the error is in, all the rest is irrelevant.  It is very impolite to ask people to do your work for you, and then not even make sure they don't have to wade through mountains of badly formatted irrelevant code.

Comment: Thank you for your help with advising about the indentation. Apologies for posting excessive code, a previous commenter said that I didn't post enough information.

I am learning from online tutorials, so I am still learning and am still trying to understand phrases like method, so I didn't know what an undefined method was, and I had never seen the phrase pop before. This is the first exercise where i can called code from within the terminal, so I didn't understand how it related. Now I do. 

Thank you for your advice. I will try to be less of a noob moving forward. We all start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  word = word.pop
  puts word
end
```

In Ruby, local variables are determined at parse time. So, during parsing, Ruby sees an assignment to `word`, and will create a local variable named `word`, which is undefined but evaluates to `nil`. At runtime, Ruby will try to assign to `word`, using the right-hand side of the assignment, which also references `word` itself. Since `word` hasn't been assigned yet, it evaluates to `nil`, which results in a call to `pop` on `nil`, which doesn't have a `pop` method.

Presumably, you meant to call `pop` on the parameter binding `words`, not the local variable `word`. Note that any halfway decent Ruby IDE would probably have warned you about the unused parameter.